# My Ionic app doesn't open on iPhone 5 on iOS 10.3.3

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, ionic-framework

Recently I launched my first app in Apple store (ProLead). It is a business-oriented application. It is working correctly, but when on my iPhone 5 it does not open, the application crashes instantly.

Someone knows the reason, because it works right on the latest devices. [Here is the link for Apple Store](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/prolead/id1450297959?mt=8).

If you need information that I did not give here, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I discovered that the problem is that the Iphone 5 uses 32 bit architecture, since one of the plugins in my project needs a 64 bit architecture, so the program crashes at startup, if someone has a similar problem, it probably is same mistake.